# Splitting words by whitespace without affecting brackets content using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to tokenize sentences using `re` in python like an example mentioned here:

`I want a (hot chocolate)[food] and (two)[quantity] boxes of (crispy bacon)[food]`

I wish to tokenize by splitting them using whitespace but without affecting the bracket set.
For example, I want the split list as:

`["I", "want", "a", "(hot chocolate)[food]", "and", "(two)[quantity]", "boxes", "of", "(crispy bacon)[food]"]`

How do I write the `re.split` expression to achieve the same.

Comment: Are the words in braces always in sets of `()[]`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build an entity classifier without using nlp packages or tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the regex pattern: `\s(?!\w+\))`

```py
import re
s = """I want a (hot chocolate)[food] and (two)[quantity] boxes of (crispy bacon)[food]"""
print(re.split(r'\s(?!\w+\))',s))
# ['I', 'want', 'a', '(hot chocolate)[food]', 'and', '(two)[quantity]', 'boxes', 'of', '(crispy bacon)[food]']
```

`\s(?!\w+\))`
The above pattern will NOT match any space that is followed by a word and a `)`, basically any space inside ')'.

Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/SRHEXO/1

Test python here: https://ideone.com/reIIcU

EDIT: Answer to the question from your comment:

Since your input has multiple words inside `( )`, you can change the pattern to `[\s,](?![\s\w]+\))`
Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/Ea9XlY/1

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Can I add a special characters like commas, colons, etc removal to this expression? For example, 
(Four)[quantity] (nuggets)[food], (one)[quantity] (vanilla)[sub_type] (thickshake)[food]

Comment: @KrishnaEcrio Do you mean that you want to remove special chars from the string? if Yes then that looks like a new StackOverflow question. If no then can you explain more?

Comment: Oh, let me explain. If we take this example, 
(Four)[quantity] (nuggets)[food], (one)[quantity] (vanilla)[sub_type] (thickshake)[food]

If you notice, there's a comma immediately after (nuggets)[food]. So when we split it, the comma also becomes a part of it right, like "(nuggets)[food]," . So I was wondering if that can be removed.

Comment: @KrishnaEcrio Yes, they can be removed while splitting by using `[\s,](?!\w+\))`, you can add special chars inside the `[ ]`. This will not match any char inside [] which is present inside `( )` according to your question.

Comment: I was trying this for entities with multiple words like (three)[entity_quantity] (cheese pops with dips)[entity_food] . It kind splits up within the round brackets too. And the starting of the rounded brackets "(" gets cut too. I'm kinda new to regex so, bear with me. Here's the link: https://regex101.com/r/PZJOgz/1

Comment: @KrishnaEcrio I have updated the answer to work with multiple words inside ().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243605/discussion-between-krishna-ecrio-and-anothergatsby).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions, no matter how clever, are not always the right answer.

```
def split(s):
    result = []
    brace_depth = 0
    temp = ''
    for ch in s:
        if ch == ' ' and brace_depth == 0:
            result.append(temp[:])
            temp = ''
        elif ch == '(' or ch == '[':
            brace_depth += 1
            temp += ch
        elif ch == ']' or ch == ')':
            brace_depth -= 1
            temp += ch
        else:
            temp += ch
    if temp != '':
        result.append(temp[:])
    return result
```

```
>>> s="I want a (hot chocolate)[food] and (two)[quantity] boxes of (crispy bacon)[food]"
>>> split(s)
['I', 'want', 'a', '(hot chocolate)[food]', 'and', '(two)[quantity]', 'boxes', 'of', '(crispy bacon)[food]']
```

Answer (score -1):

The regex for string is `\s`. So using this with `re.split`:

```
print(re.split("[\s]", "I want a (hot chocolate)[food] and (two)[quantity] boxes of (crispy bacon)[food]"))
```

The output is `['I', 'want', 'a', '(hot', 'chocolate)[food]', 'and', '(two)[quantity]', 'boxes', 'of', '(crispy', 'bacon)[food]']`

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirements in the question, as `"(hot"` should not be split from `"chocolate)[food]"`.