# Python split string by whitespaces except when bracket

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am looking for a regular expression in Python for splitting a string of the form :

'I love hjk(d, k, l) and hjk(d, k, l).' into 'I', 'love', 'hjk(d, k, l)', 'and', 'hjk(d, k , l)'.

Thanks

Comment: please show, input string, and output string and any code you have tried so far, thanks

Comment: Check the answers provided
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732405/splitting-words-by-whitespace-without-affecting-brackets-content-using-regex

Comment: Input String is "I love hjk(d, k, l) and hjk(d, k, l)". I would like to split it by whitespace except not by the whitespace inside the brackets. So it should give me "I", "love", "hjk(d, k, l)", "and", "hjk(d,k,l)"

Comment: The link does not work when there are commas and for digits

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = 'I love hjk(d, k, l) and hjk(d, k, l).'
print(re.split(r'\s(?!\w+\))',s))
```

Output:

```
['I', 'love', 'hjk(d,', 'k, l)', 'and', 'hjk(d,', 'k, l).']
```